# What are the current most challenging MNIST-like tasks aiming to achieve the lowest error rate?

Tags: dataset, image-processing, conv-neural-network, model-evaluation, computer-vision

For example there is [the MNIST database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database) which is used to test artificial neural network (ANN), however it's not so challenging, because some hierarchical systems of *convolutional neural networks* manages to get an error rate of 0.23 percent and the same with other OCR tests.

Therefore OCR datasets are '*no longer perceived as an exemplar of "artificial intelligence"*'<sup>[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence)</sup>.

Are there any similar equivalent image-recognition tests, especially these which have the most challenging tasks with dataset which are commonly used as benchmark tests to challenge the AI which are fairly reliable and they're possible to pass (e.g. by humans), but most networks are struggling to achieve the lower error rate?

Comment: You might want to ask on opendata.stackexchange.com , since pure data requests are considered off-topic here.

Comment: See also: The [HASYv2 dataset](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08380) (my paper). The data is similar to MNIST, but 369 classes. The best model has an accuracy of ~82%. ([my answer on opendata](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10625/5487))